# Como fazer Insert no Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Usando o SQLite e Android Studio como fazer INSERT ?

Vamos usar como exemplo uma tabela com os seguintes dados: 
Nome String
Idade int
Media double

Usando tipos de dados diferente;

Comment: Tenta usar este tutorial como exemplo: http://mobilesiri.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-using-android-studio/

Comment: Documentação: [Como salvar dados em bancos de dados SQL](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=pt-br)